# Calculating ISBN-10 — modulus not working in C

Tags: c, modulus

I am trying to validate ISBN-10 numbers in C. My logic is that each number multiplied by it's radix, when summed will be divisible by 11. But, even valid ISBN numbers are getting rejected.So I added print statements, and I can't understand why I am getting this output. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
int isValid(long long int number){
int sum=0, i=0,j=10;
long long int base=10;
fflush(stdout);
printf("num=%ld\n",number);
while(i<10){
    j=number%base;
    sum += j*(i+1);
    printf("n=%d i=%d sum=%d\n",j,i,sum);
    base*=10;
    i++;
    }
return sum%11;
}
```

And here's the printout for ISBN - 0321334876

```
num=321334876
n=8 i=0 sum=8
n=88 i=1 sum=184
n=788 i=2 sum=2548
n=3788 i=3 sum=17700
n=13788 i=4 sum=86640
n=413788 i=5 sum=2569368
n=6413788 i=6 sum=47465884
n=96413788 i=7 sum=818776188
n=696413788 i=8 sum=-1503434312
n=106479196 i=9 sum=-438642352
```

Comment: You need to multiply individual *digits*. In your code, you are multiplying % 10 for the last digit `6` (correct) but % 100 for the preceding, leading to `76` which should be just the second-to-last `7`. (Quite confusing, your sample output seems to report `88`.) You are also overflowing your integers somewhere, but that is just due to the too large numbers.

Comment: Ref: [ISBN-10 check digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number#ISBN-10_check_digits)

Comment: Note: Suspect in the end code should be `!(sum%11)`.

Comment: Thanks @Jongware please post as an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your calculation method is wrong; see, e.g., [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) for a proper example.
2. No need to use a very large variable, it's rather easy to use a *string* as input.
3. You can sum up to 9 digits and check if the last digit is the expected one, or check all 10 and see if the result is `0`. My program below does both; parsing a nine-number ISBN returns the expected check digit (where a value of `10` should be interpreted as the traditional `X`).
4. For a 10-digit ISBN my program returns the remainder, so `0` is actually the indicator for "valid".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int isValid (char *isbn)
{
    int sum=0, i=0, j, pos=0;
    printf("num=%s\n", isbn);

    while (isbn[pos])
    {
        if (i == 9 && tolower(isbn[pos]) == 'x')
        {
            i++;
            sum += 10*i;
            printf("n=%d i=%d sum=%d\n",j,i,sum);
        } else
        if (isdigit (isbn[pos]))
        {
            i++;
            j = isbn[pos]-'0';
            sum += j*i;
            printf("n=%d i=%d sum=%d\n",j,i,sum);
        }
        pos++;
    }
    if (i == 9 || i == 10)
        return sum % 11;
    return -1;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf ("usage: isbn [isbn number]\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf ("checksum: %d\n", isValid (argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

Sample input and output (debug strings omitted):

```
> ./isbn 032133487
checksum: 6

> ./isbn 0321334876
checksum: 0

> ./isbn 1-84356-028-3
checksum: 0

> ./isbn 0-8044-2957-X
checksum: 0
```